# Start MainActivity when android kill my process

Tags: java, android

When my app is inactive for some time android kills its process, making all static variables null. destroying activities etc. I want my app to launch MainActivity(activity that is declared as launcher in manifest) instead of activity that was in foreground when my app got minimalized and later killed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **right way** to do this would be to store the data you need (that you are storing just on your static vars) on the database and use the memory just as cache.

The not so good *hammer time* way to do it... is simple. In each `onCreate` of the Activities that need that info, check if the info is null, and if it is, invoke `finish()` and `startActivity` with the one you want.

```
@override
 protected void onCreate(){
       super.onCreate();
       ...
       if(Singleton.getInfo() == null){
        this.finish();
        startActivity(...)
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or u can go to MainActivity with intent`s if you need pass some information from that activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possibility : As described in [Clearing the back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing) you can add  `clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` to the root activity :

> If this attribute is set to "true" in the root activity of a task, the
>   stack is cleared down to the root activity whenever the user leaves
>   the task and returns to it. In other words, it's the opposite of
>   alwaysRetainTaskState. The user always returns to the task in its
>   initial state, even after a leaving the task for only a moment.